# Salesforce Formula error

Tags: formula

I am trying to create new formula field (Text) but I am receiving an error that says "Compiled formula is too big to execute (8,351 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters".  What am I doing wrong?
Score__c is a number field

```
IF((Score__c)>=13,"Critical",
    IF(AND((Score__c)>=10,(Score__c)< 13),"Major",
        IF(AND((Score__c)>=6,(Score__c)<= 9),"Medium",
            IF((Score__c)<6,"Low","None"
             )
         )
     )
)
```

I have tried using Text and Value but doesn't works

Comment: About the only way I can see this formula resulting in that large of a compile size is if `Score__c` is itself a formula field. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a CASE statement so `Score__c` is referenced only once , assumes values are 0,1,2, ...13+.

Solution is practical as long as scores are integers within a small range. Would not work if scores could be between 1-1000 as CASE statement would get too large.

```
CASE(Score__c,
     0,"Low",
     1,"Low",
     ...
     6,"Medium",
     ...
     9,"Medium,
     10,"High",
     ...
     12,"High",
     "Critical"   /* 13+ */
    )
```

Comment: Thank you it worked